# How do I remove blood from my face?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I am replaying Saints Row The Third after a long time. My player character has a bloody mouth. It is bothering me a little. I have tried the options, but did not find a place where I can re-customize my player character.

I also purchased a plastic surgery place called *Image As Designed*. But still can not find a way to remove this bloodied face.

[image: Here is what I look like :]

How do I get rid of the bloodied face?

Comment: I *think* it's under features. It's in the same customization option that lets you add bandages and the like, but I'm not 100% on what area of customization that is in.

Comment: You got blood on your face?  You big disgrace!  [Waving your banner all over the place.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tJYN-eG1zk)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My character is female, but I'm pretty sure I found the same facial option that you're currently using.

You need to go to `Make-Up`, then under that heading, go to `Items`. It looks like you've got the "Busted Nose" option on right now.

[image: makeup1]

Simply switch it to "Nothing" and you should be cleaned up nicely!
[image: makeup2]